# React Redux reducer not Updating State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a reducer which doesn't seem to be updating the state at all whenever I called the 'LOGIN' action. It could be a problem with my React Redux code. It's either my component is not getting re rendered whenever the store's state changes or the reducer is not changing the stores state at all.

Reducer ------

```
const initialState = {
    messages: [],
    loginDetails: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    },
    activeUsers: [],
    loginActive: false
}

const messageReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_MESSAGE': 
            if(state.messages.length < 50) {
                let newStateMessages = [...state.messages]
                newStateMessages.unshift(action.payload);
                console.log(newStateMessages);
                return {...state, messages: newStateMessages};
            } else {
                let newStateMessages = [...state.messages]
                newStateMessages.pop();
                newStateMessages.unshift(action.payload);
                return {...state, newStateMessages};
            }
        case 'LOGIN':
            console.log('LOGIN');
            console.log(action);
            const newLoginDetails = {
                email: action.payload.email,
                password: action.payload.password
            };
            console.log({...state, loginDetails: newLoginDetails});
            return {...state, loginDetails: newLoginDetails};
        case 'UPDATE_USERS':
            const newActiveUsers = action.payload;
            return {...state, activeUsers: newActiveUsers};
        case 'LOGIN_ACTIVE':
            return {...state, loginActive: true};
        case 'LOGIN_EXIT':
            return {...state, loginActive: false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const store = createStore(messageReducer);
```

React Redux connect -----

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return { ...state }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

This mapStateToProps returns...

```
{
   activeUsers: []
   dispatch: ƒ dispatch(action)
   loginActive: true
   loginDetails: {email: "", password: ""}
   messages: []
   __proto__: Object
}
```

when it should return...

```
{
   activeUsers: []
   loginActive: true
   loginDetails: {email: "example@gmail.com", password: 
   "password"}
   messages: []
   __proto__: Object
}
```

I have tested for sure that the dispatch to the reducer is getting called, and the payload is correct. However, the reducer is failing to update the state with the LOGIN action type.

Comment: Provided code samples show no signs of what may cause the problem. Would you provide executable snippet, reproducing your problem?

Comment: The console statements in `case 'LOGIN'` are being hit, but the props contain no value? Did you verify what state is in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: What does the `action` parameter look like? Can you include the `console.log(action)` output for the `LOGIN` action

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({activeUsers,loginActive,loginDetails,messages}) => ({
   activeUsers,
   loginActive,
   loginDetails,
   messages
})
```